# Using an insertion sort for a structure causing an error

Tags: c++, sorting, pointers, struct

I have a Student structure that will be a Student array containing the name of a student, their four GPA numbers, and their average GPA.

```
struct Student
{
  string name;
  double gpa[4];
  double averageGPA;
};
```

I am trying to use an insertion sort to sort this array of Student structures by the name of the student in alphabetical order. I have come up with this so far with ptr being a pointer to the structure. I have tried running it and I am getting an error that says no match for 'operator='. It must be the way I am trying to compare the elements, that is causing this error?

```
void insertionSort(Student* ptr[])
{
    const int MAX = 10;
    int current = 1;                
    int last = MAX - 1;         
    int temp;                       
    int walker;                     

    while (current <= last) 
    {    
        temp = ptr[current];        
        walker = current - 1;   
        while (walker >= 0 && temp < ptr[walker])   
        {       
            ptr[walker+1] = ptr[walker];  
            walker = walker - 1;      
        } 

        ptr[walker+1] = temp;   
        current = current + 1;      
    }
}
```

Comment: > "I'm not sure if this insertion sort will work"

Did you try running it as part of a program to verify whether it works or not? If so, what did you get?

Comment: Design some test cases where you know what correct result should be. Try it. I fit doesn't work, use both thinking and debugger.

Comment: This code has a certain error at `ptr[walker+1] = temp;` you are trying to assign an `int` to a `Student`. You will have to write specific code to swap `Student` considering all its member variables.

Comment: If you only want to sort by the student's name why not make it "ptr[walker].name" and shouldn't you be using the strcmp() function? Also - Ahmed Akhtar is right.  temp is an int and it isn't even an "int *temp" or "Student temp"

Comment: You can find out if it works by trying to use it. Have you done so? If not, please do. This site is not a replacement for writing code and actually trying it. If you have an actual problem, ask a question here. If you're simply avoiding doing  the work of testing your own code, you're in the wrong place (and you should probably just avoid writing code).

Comment: @KenWhite My apologies if it sounds like I am trying to avoid doing the work. I just came up with this while working on another part and did not even think about testing it yet. I should've tested it first before asking. You are definitely correct. I don't deserve to be asking this here. I'll make sure not to go here before testing anything first.

Comment: @MarkManning I think you're right. I am getting an error that says no match for 'operator=' for that line. I forgot about using the strcmp function, I think that should fix it. I'm very new to structures and thought I could compare each element like an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a complete solution to your problem using insertion sort:

```
struct Student
{
 string name;
 double gpa[4];
 double averageGPA;
};
```

I have defined a function to swap two `Student` entities:

```
void swap(Student* a, Student* b)
{
 Student temp;

 temp.name = a->name;
 for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
  temp.gpa[i] = a->gpa[i];
 temp.averageGPA = a->averageGPA;

 a->name = b->name;
 for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
 a->gpa[i] = b->gpa[i];
 a->averageGPA = b->averageGPA;

 b->name = temp.name;
 for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
 b->gpa[i] = temp.gpa[i];
 b->averageGPA = temp.averageGPA;
}
```

This is the basic **insertion sort** algorithm:

```
void insertionSort(Student* ptr)
{
 const int MAX = 10;
 int current = 1;
 int last = MAX - 1;         
 Student *temp;
 int walker;

 while (current <= last) 
 {    
    temp = &ptr[current];        
    walker = current - 1;   
    while (walker >= 0 && temp->name < ptr[walker].name)   
    {
        swap(temp,&ptr[walker]);
        temp = &ptr[walker];
        walker = walker - 1;      
    } 
    current = current + 1;      
 }
}
```

I have tested this code and it works.

Basically, where you are passing your `Student` array to **insertion sort** like `void insertionSort(Student* ptr[])` is incorrect because you either use the `[]` or the `*` and they are somewhat alternatives to represent the same thing.

Comment: I really appreciate your help, but you did not have to use up your time to make a complete solution for me. I was only hoping to get advice to put me in the right direction. I am not allowed to make a swap function for this homework assignment, but thanks to your help, I think I can find a way to make it work without using the swap function. Thank you.

Comment: @Mark That was no problem, actually what I want you to understand is that you have to handle the contents of a `struct` explicity whenever copying it to another one. Just assigning the object itself does nothing and this is what we call a **shallow copy**. You can look into **Deep Copy and Shallow Copy** concepts to understand it better.

Comment: @Mark Also, arrays are already passed by reference, so no need to send `Student* ptr[]` as an argument. Either of `Student ptr[]` or `Student* ptr` will do. And passing `Student* ptr[]` could be useful when you want to pass an array of arrays, for say, if representing students to organize them in different disciplines.

Comment: I see now! I had no idea I had to handle the contents explicitly since I am new with using structures. I will for sure look into those concepts. Thank you for pointing out what I need to understand when using `struct`.